# Using clustermq R package as a parallel backend for foreach

Tags: r, parallel-processing, zeromq, parallel-foreach

I've started using the clustermq package as a parallel backend for a drake pipeline, and have been very impressed over the performance improvements that I've observed.  I'm interested in evaluating the use of clustermq / rzmq in settings outside of drake, but seemingly can't get the example using foreach listed in the [User Guide](https://mschubert.github.io/clustermq/articles/userguide.html) (in the subsection titled "As parallel foreach backend") to work.  What am I missing here?

In the example below on my 4-core machine, I would expect the following code to run in close to 5 seconds, yet it runs in close to 20 seconds.  When I use similar code to run some heavy processing, I'm only observing one core doing significant work.

```r
library(foreach)
(n_cores <- parallel::detectCores())
#> [1] 4
clustermq::register_dopar_cmq(n_jobs = n_cores)
system.time(foreach(i = seq_len(n_cores)) %dopar% Sys.sleep(5))
#> Submitting 4 worker jobs (ID: 6856) ...
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.118   0.022  20.187
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the clustermq package kindly responded to a GitHub issue that I posted regarding this.  In short, there is an option `clustermq.scheduler` that can be set to specify the type of scheduling that clustermq employs.  For my case, since the option was unset, clustermq was defaulting to local (i.e. sequential) scheduling.  To perform parallel processing on your local machine, you can set the `clustermq.scheduler` option to `"multicore"`.  So in total, this results in the following.

```r
library(foreach)
(n_cores <- parallel::detectCores())
#> [1] 4
clustermq::register_dopar_cmq(n_jobs = n_cores)
options(clustermq.scheduler = "multicore")
system.time(foreach(i = seq_len(n_cores)) %dopar% Sys.sleep(5))
#> Submitting 4 worker jobs (ID: 7206) ...
#> Running 4 calculations (1 objs/0 Mb common; 1 calls/chunk) ...
#> Master: [5.6s 3.6% CPU]; Worker: [avg 1.3% CPU, max 2475916.0 Mb]
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.188   0.065   5.693
```

Answer (score 0):

The good news is,
the R-console reported the work-units got dispatched to the **`4 worker jobs (ID: 6856) ...`**

To see how the acounting of CPU-usage works ( as in `unix.time()` ), test this ( the online R-code execution were not able to load either the `library(foreach)` nor the `library(doParallel)` to show the differences live, online, yet the [code](https://tio.run/##tVdNb@M2EL37VwwQBJDbmhYpiR/CtoemQbGHAkWyORWFIUtMrI1sOZKMJFjsb0@HkmyJcmLE65Qn2iTnvXkczmiKl5fbKK7yAn6F280qrtJ85cATjOHbCLYjvQWnmT3BJ/BwsdDVpmg2dtt0VmqwRrftJ2hgzHwCFE2MR99HoyyPEtzXx17Z2LdIzYEM0hXQcLDWjHmEsJ8mOwDqCtmn1bdzb@ywkOKA8Z4l257TzH7eGb43rGHa/z208H3Um6J/@dpYytfGtdKBJL1Lq5KUOi7RZ47nR9fPJanSpXbGo/K5rPSy@QVGGeOLW0v15jZ0S0fxwoEUDZb6YZZpo@Esxv/Lmu95kq@j4vyAwdEZ2DZb/xg1QuLmM5idPtAKqkCKzeqj7KGdLVWAmuqPjE2pixBc4lLeylD/cinGc7QuddIsyj4a/XA0NkCDKx1lZs4EhZv2EJUumHur9wQKLv6@gXIRFToEKYnrw3mPZPMMTiQpLJKBRZLRjqTHeyRlR9IXfZJKEWWTZO9U8ku6TFd3UFb5eq0TiKrwvSQ9uCyKHHde4Okovsdz0R2mKaEE48yHtIQqzyHOcnzrVQ7VQkOGaBWEcPmk4415urCIskondcg17wjA/0Fxd/oylM19izouBl6rLyO@9Fp9GfFUX19p6SvxVK3vlqQ8laRPfC/ok6ReRxIX5TYIfCKCLUmfcOp3JLkYkPRVnyS@hBNJSsKZraTqSOKi2iopifJYS1ISIYK3nhOSVLRPEo@dRpK5JGDMUlLuSOKiVKwhySihqNhNe4gr1ZEUQyWpdd381Jj0AsKoRdIVO5K4yGl73TiXvE1MOPdE77oxDGyS@MQ7kk0BOoVkgKGGuef16w4CQlmbPQNDrFUSD8n@dfNgkJgYtUieqmQgiCutxES7FI@LgddeN86F3z4cnDO/T9Idkqyz54fV40VVrctwOn18fCRfkzxPMk3ifDnVdd7Tk2KSr7J0paf/X8U2/mFy102pwy@Y2CnHv8BfRrSAGZXuf8d/Xi9PeNH9KHCtzO@5@xXbQpMDNM@E/iE030Lz7Toj90vvQd@4lP4RaNL2TezX0EO@cVdw2aK9WkMHStq@4SW8WUNpgOX@2BraZSyTVdtoS8ynOZYOF0tYQ/6dVTSQb0rFCK/DoEXzh2i8LrpHoGHqcS00LF69cigU7dDkAI1SlJIfg6Ywf1nZmPV8UyQQrMtYfICGpcOVx/hGJfGkFQa8Q6Mmi6sdmje8N08RF6vs@9E8QTi3lOTd88VFJfyRaUyydF5ExbPT9jmmF3G23Q12VtjZRFmmszBMdKXj6sIsOGPcdga/wT/0X/DxRJxtEKZYPoRhoe9SM5/VXdEsXj6YbulrPjcNWdc2nR0YcHX55@frL5dXEO3wJ3N8FnqV7LVSR7ZnrG3PavrXmzm@ocp8@PrwmBf3uoCaqfP5D3zTMuBjIIQ0m1thocXfagnbVfwwxw8OqKOIgQkPKsXLy38) ought be clear on how to do that on a properly configured localhost R system :

```
factor = function( x ) {
         if (      x < 3 ) return( x )
         else              return( x * factor( x - 1 ) )
}

load   = function( n ) {
         for ( l in 1:n ) {
               base <- factor( 1078 )
               for ( k in 2:1111 ){
                     base <- ( base + factor( k ) ) / factor( k )
               }
         }
}

op <- options( digits.secs = 6 )

Sys.time()
system.time(                                           load( 100 ) )
Sys.time()
system.time( foreach( i = seq_len( n_cores ) ) %dopar% load( 100 ) )

Sys.time()

# ___________________________________________________________________
# tio.run
# ___________________________________________________________________
#
# factor(   78 )                                                     user: 0.016 system: 0.001 elapsed: 0.018
# factor(  178 )                                                     user: 0.016 system: 0.002 elapsed: 0.018 Real: 0.271 User: 0.180 Sys.: 0.059 CPU share: 88.04 %
# factor( 1078 )                                                     user: 0.017 system: 0.005 elapsed: 0.021 Real: 0.236 User: 0.188 Sys.: 0.047 CPU share: 99.94 %
# factor( 2178 )                                  Timing stopped at: user: 0.017 system: 0.005 elapsed: 0.023 Error: C stack usage  7972624 is too close to the limit : Execution halted
#
# load(   4 )                                                        user: 2.230 system: 0.005 elapsed: 2.253 Real: 2.483 User: 2.398 Sys.: 0.048 CPU share: 98.25 %
# load(   8 )                                                        user: 4.435 system: 0.013 elapsed: 4.481 Real: 4.753 User: 4.614 Sys.: 0.067 CPU share: 98.49 %
# load(  16 )                                                        user: 8.620 system: 0.009 elapsed: 8.693 Real: 8.932 User: 8.775 Sys.: 0.059 CPU share: 98.91 %
# load(  32 )                                                        user:20.522 system: 0.018 elapsed:20.892 Real:21.167 User:20.699 Sys.: 0.077 CPU share: 98.15 %
# load(  64 )                                                        user:35.212 system: 0.007 elapsed:35.611 Real:35.861 User:35.374 Sys.: 0.053 CPU share: 98.78 %
# load( 100 )                                                        user:54.721 system: 0.009 elapsed:55.128 Real:55.377 User:54.875 Sys.: 0.065 CPU share: 99.21 %
# load( 104 )                                                        user:57.087 system: 0.012 elapsed:57.532 Real:57.743 User:57.245 Sys.: 0.060 CPU share: 99.24 %
#
# ___________________________________________________________________
# https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online/
# ___________________________________________________________________
#
# factor(   78 ) CPU Time: 0.27 sec(s), Mem: 52532 kB(s)             user: 0.028 system: 0.000 elapsed: 0.030
# factor(  178 ) CPU Time: 0.28 sec(s), Mem: 53212 kB(s)             user: 0.024 system: 0.004 elapsed: 0.028
# factor( 1078 ) CPU Time: 0.27 sec(s), Mem: 56884 kB(s)             user: 0.024 system: 0.008 elapsed: 0.037
# factor( 2178 ) CPU Time: 0.28 sec(s), Mem: 60768 kB(s) stopped at: user: 0.028 system: 0.004 elapsed: 0.032 Error: C stack usage  7971588 is too close to the limit : Execution halted
#
#
# load(  2 ) executed in  4.025 sec(s)                               user: 2.584 system: 0.008 elapsed: 2.630
# load(  4 ) executed in  6.005 sec(s)                               user: 4.704 system: 0.016 elapsed: 4.791
# load(  8 ) executed in 11.036 sec(s)                               user: 9.372 system: 0.028 elapsed: 9.572
# load( 16 ) executed in 20.085 sec(s)                               user:18.388 system: 0.068 elapsed:18.789
# load( 32 ) executed in 39.093 sec(s)                               user:37.664 system: 0.060 elapsed:37.974


# library(foreach)
# (n_cores <- parallel::detectCores())
## > [1] 4
# clustermq::register_dopar_cmq( n_jobs = n_cores ) ############################ REGISTER a parallel-backend
# system.time( foreach( i = seq_len( n_cores ) ) %dopar% load( 200 ) )
## > Submitting 4 worker jobs (ID: 6856) ...
## >    user  system elapsed 
## >   0.118   0.022  20.187
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So if I am understanding this correctly, the `load` function is constructed so as to observe the `foreach` + `%dopar%` construct when performing a computation-heavy task.  Strangely though, whenever I run the line `foreach( i = seq_len( n_cores ) ) %dopar% load( 200 )`, I am getting an error `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`.